# How to open new window on my machine when attaching to tmux session with SSH connection?

Tags: macos, ssh, debian, vps, tmux

I'm connencted to Debian VPS via macOS terminal and SSH. Is there a way I could open a new terminal window on my mac when I attach to a tmux session in my VPS?

Answer (score 0):

In macos settings->Sharing, enable "Remote login"

Then in your VPS

```
ssh macos << EOF
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "/bin/bash"'
EOF
```